# RxJava poor performance with JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, rx-java, java-11

I am using `RxJava` with `JavaFx`, I can't help but notice the poor performance, whenever I click a `button` that executes a `task`, the `button` stays highlighted until the method completes, the application behaves as if its running the method on the UI thread. When I replace the same `Rx` call with a normal Java `thread` I noticed much better performance, the button highlight doesn't stay on and the overall app transitions seem much better. Below is a sample of my `Rx` call

```
   Single.just(someMethod())
                .observeOn(JavaFxScheduler.platform())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new DisposableSingleObserver<>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Result result) {
                        //get my result
                        this.dispose();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                        logger.error(throwable);
                        this.dispose();
                    }
                });
```

I use `RxJava` in `Android` and it performs great compared to this. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: You're calling `Single.just(someMethod())` which means the result of `someMethod()` is evaluated before invoking `Single.just`. In other words, the result is eagerly evaluated (on whatever thread is creating the `Single`). You should use one of the methods of `Single` that make the evaluation of the value lazy (e.g. `Single.fromCallable` or something—not that familiar with RxJava).

Comment: @Slaw interesting, I never knew this.

Comment: Note this isn't specific to RxJava. You are passing the result of a method call as an argument to another method. This requires the first method be evaluated before the second method, otherwise you have no result to pass as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

During assembly time, `someMethod()` will be evaluated eagerly. You want to defer its evaluation till the time the subscription takes place . Not sure if there's how it's done in `RxJava`, but in `Reactor`, you can use: `Mono.defer() -> someMethod()`.